# ActiveMerchant: Send item details to paypal url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, express-checkout, activemerchant

I am trying to integrate `paypal-express-checkout` with my `rails 4` app using `active merchant` gem. I have successfully redirected to the `paypal` but I am not able to send the item details (Only amount get passed to the `paypal`).

**Here what I did:**

```
total_amount = cart_items.sum(:amount)

items = []
cart_items.each_with_index do |item, index|
  items << {
      "L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME#{index+1}" => item.product_name,
      "L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT#{index+1}" => to_cents(item.amount),
      "L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY#{index+1}" => item.quantity
  }
end

response = EXPRESS_GATEWAY.setup_purchase(total_amount,
                                          :items             => items,
                                          :return_url        => new_order_url,
                                          :cancel_return_url => root_url
)
redirect_to EXPRESS_GATEWAY.redirect_url_for(response.token)
```

**And what actually happened:**

[image]

I have checked the **response** for any error but I cannot find any:

```
(byebug) response
#<ActiveMerchant::Billing::PaypalExpressResponse:0x00000112831748 @params={"timestamp"=>"2015-07-17T12:43:53Z", "ack"=>"Success", "correlation_id"=>"7cd013c59c176", "version"=>"72", "build"=>"17403434", "token"=>"EC-94A59640DJ829313S", "Timestamp"=>"2015-07-17T12:43:53Z", "Ack"=>"Success", "CorrelationID"=>"7cd013c59c176", "Version"=>"72", "Build"=>"17403434", "Token"=>"EC-94A59640DJ829313S"}, @message="Success", @success=true, @test=true, @authorization=nil, @fraud_review=false, @error_code=nil, @emv_authorization=nil, @avs_result={"code"=>nil, "message"=>nil, "street_match"=>nil, "postal_match"=>nil}, @cvv_result={"code"=>nil, "message"=>nil}>
```

note `"message"=>nil,` and `@message="Success",`

Can anyone please suggest what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through the code, I found the solution to the problem that leads to another problem: "The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts."

## What I did:

```
total_amount = cart_items.sum(:amount)

# item must be in [{}, {}] format
items = []
cart_items.each do |item|
  items << {
      :name => item.product_name.to_s,
      :amount => to_cents(item.amount),
      :quantity => item.quantity
  }
end

response = EXPRESS_GATEWAY.setup_purchase(total_amount,
                                      :items             => items,
                                      :return_url        => new_order_url,
                                      :cancel_return_url => root_url
)
redirect_to EXPRESS_GATEWAY.redirect_url_for(response.token)
```

Here, `total_amount` is in `dollar` and `amount` is in `cent`. I have changed the currency for `total_amount` to `cent` but still no work. I don't know how paypal calculates the **total amount** from `quantity` and `amount`.

## Actually what happened:

When I checked the value for `total_amount` and `calculated_total_amount_from_each_item`, there I saw no problem with `total_amount` and  `calculated amount`.

[image]
[image]

Still the original question has not been solved. Can any one suggest me with right direction.

After googling for the problems, I found out [this](https://github.com/activemerchant/active_merchant/issues/1706) issue in github. In order for paypal to work one must include `shipping`, `tax` and `handling` option in the `setup_purchase` function. Thanks for the issue and the solution. I did finally solved the problems.